# Grunt : SCSS files not compiled

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am trying to compile scss files with grunt. Using theses modules

1. `grunt-contrib-sass`
2. `grunt-contrib-watch`
3. `grunt-contrib-concat`

that being said, all my regular css files gets compiled into my main css file but none of my .scss files does. I have tried to manually compile my files in command line and it does work fine (`sass styles.scss:style.css`), so it has nothing to do with my .scss or ruby. What am I doing wrong?

This is how my Gruntfile.js looks like

```
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

var jsFileList = [
    'bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
    'sources/js/dom_ready.js'
];

var cssFileList = [
    'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css',
    'sources/sass/styles.scss',
    'sources/sass/responsive.scss',
];

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'assets/css/styles.css': cssFileList
            }
        }
    },
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        dist: {
            src: jsFileList,
            dest: 'assets/js/script.js'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: cssFileList,
            tasks: ['sass'],
        },
        js: {
            files: jsFileList,
            tasks: ['concat']
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'sass',
    'concat'
]);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using concat.

The first thing to do is to merge all you scss and css into one bigger scss files (which I called for convenience **concat.scss**).

Then you can generate that scss file using sass task.

This is how your **Gruntfile.js** should look.

```
var jsFileList = [
    ...
];

var cssFileList = [
    ...
];

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        js: {
            src: cssFileList,
            dest: 'sources/sass/generated/concat.scss'
        },
        css: {
            src: jsFileList,
            dest: 'assets/js/script.js'
        }
    },
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                noCache : true,
                style: 'compressed',
                sourcemap: "none"
            },
            files:{
                'assets/css/styles.css' : 'sources/sass/generated/concat.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: cssFileList,
            tasks: ['concat','sass']
        },
        js: {
            files: jsFileList,
            tasks: ['concat']
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default',[
    'concat',
    'sass'
]);
grunt.registerTask('sass',['concat','sass']);
```

Your file structure should look like this

```
/root
    /bower_components
        ...
    /assets
        /css
            styles.css
        /js
            script.js
    /sources
        js
            ...
        sass
            /generated
                concat.scss
            /inc
                ...
            /main
                ...
                styles.scss
```